# white space issue with UIText field

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i have an UITextField which is allowing space

using the following code snippet it trims all the white space from the string (Text Field Text)

```
NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
NSString *trimmed = [rawString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
```

but i want to trim only the starting space of the Text that means

Example: @"   SAMPLE TEXT"= @"SAMPLE TEXT"

can any one help me how to achieve this

Comment: Clarify: `stringByTrimming` doesn't remove all the spaces. It only removes the ones at the beginning and end of the string. The ones in between are left alone. `___bla_bla_bla___` becomes `bla_bla_bla` and not `blablabla`. Knowing this, do you want this to become `bla_bla_bla___` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the first character that is not a whitespace or newline. Then create a substring from that character's location and onwards.

```
NSString *justLeaveAPonyTail = @"   Bla bla bla    ";
NSCharacterSet *allExceptWhitespace = [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] invertedSet];
NSRange range = [justLeaveAPonyTail rangeOfCharacterFromSet:allExceptWhitespace];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) 
{
    justLeaveAPonyTail = [justLeaveAPonyTail substringFromIndex:range.location];
}

// justLeaveAPonyTail is now @"Bla bla bla   "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @" SAMPLE TEXT";
NSString *newStr = [str substringFromIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *String = @" SAMPLE TEXT";
NSString *firstLetter = [String substringToIndex:0];
if ([firstLetter isEqualToString:@" "]) 
    String = [String stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@""];
```